# Node.js server for Socket.IO explanation?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, server

I have the following code:

```
express = require('express');
app = express();
http = require('http').createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
http.listen(80);
```

I know it creates a server that clients can connect to and it works. But I don't know what exactly happens. Can you explain in detail?

Also, why things don't work when I forget about Express.js and just use this line:

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
```

It appears to listen for connections. However, inside the browser when I go to http://localhost/, nothing happens. My guess is that I don't specify the directory for my app like that:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Is that why I need Express? To specify the directory?

At the client, I use:

```
socket = io('http://localhost/'); // this
socket = io(); // or this
```

None of them work with the single line code at the server-side.

Also, why do I need an HTTP server when Socket.IO uses the WebSocket protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your browser goes to http://localhost/, you need a web server that's going to respond back to the browser with a web page.  That's what Express and the `express.static()` lines were doing.  When you remove those, you do indeed have a server listening for webSocket connections on a specific path, but you don't have anything serving web pages.  So, when the browser goes to http://localhost/, there's nothing responding back with a plain web page.

> Also, why do I need an HTTP server when Socket.IO uses the WebSocket
>   protocol?

All socket.io connections start with an HTTP request.  socket.io is based on the webSocket protocol and all webSocket connections are initiated with an HTTP request.  So, to accept a socket.io connection, you need a web server that responds to an HTTP request and you then need a web server that is smart enough to recognize a request for a webSocket connection so it can "upgrade" the protocol from HTTP to webSocket.

For a well written overview of how a webSocket connection is established, see [this overview on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers).

The socket.io infrastructure then runs on top of that webSocket once it is connected.

> I know it creates a server that clients can connect to and it works.
>   But I don't know what exactly happens. Can you explain in detail?

Here's a line-by-line explanation of your code:

```
express = require('express');
```

This loads the Express library.

```
app = express();
```

This creates an Express `app` object which can be used as a webServer request handler.

```
http = require('http').createServer(app);
```

This creates a web server and passes it the Express `app` object as the webServer request handler.

```
io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

This hooks socket.io into your web server as another request handler so it can see any incoming http requests that are actually the first stage of starting a webSocket/socket.io connection.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

This tells Express that if any request is made for a web page that it should look in the __dirname for a file that matches the requested path.  If found, it should return that path.

```
http.listen(80);
```

This starts the web server listening on port 80.

> None of them work with the single line code at the server-side.

Both of those lines of code to create a socket.io connection will work when used properly.  You don't say how this code is being run.  If you're trying to run this code from a web page that the browser loads from http://localhost/, then I've already explained why that web page won't load if you don't start Express.  If you're trying to run those lines of code from a web page loaded some other way, then you're probably having a same-origin security issue were the browser by default won't let you access a domain that is different than the one the web page came from.

Comment: In case someone is wondering, __dirname is the directory where the server script is running.

Answer (score 2):

You need the express http server to deliver the socket client to the browser.

- Express server starts on port 80
- Browser connects to express on port 80, the socket.io server component delivers socket client javascript to the browser (http://localhost:80/socket.io/socket.io.js)
- Socket client (running in browser) can then connect to socket.io server